# MemoryError in Python3 when cropping audio files

Tags: python, audio, memory

I'm trying to use a pydub module to trim bits of intro/outro audio from the chapters of some audiobooks. All the files are in the range 9-19MB.
It manages to do a few files then returns MemoryError. I have 8BG of RAM so I figure I must be doing something pretty badly to have caused this.

I've run it with all other programs closed, didn't make any difference. I tried watch my memory usage in Task Manager. Usually at around 350MB, occasinally spiking to between 900-1000MB, especially at the end of each file.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os, eyed3

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User\Music\audiobooks podcasts\Narnia\Edit Testing')

NarniaList = os.listdir()

for i in NarniaList[:10]:
    print('Ammending ' + i + '...')
    track = AudioSegment.from_mp3(i)
    newcut = track[75000:-59000]
    newtitle = 'New'+i
    newcut.export(newtitle,format="mp3")
    audiofile = eyed3.load(i)
    newfile = eyed3.load(newtitle)
    newfile.tag.artist = audiofile.tag.artist 
    newfile.tag.album = audiofile.tag.album
    newfile.tag.title = audiofile.tag.title
    newfile.tag.save()
```

It manages at least 2 files everytime, the best I've got is 5. 
As far as I can tell I'm not leaving previous files open after completion but I am a total novice so I'm not really sure. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One place where your code is leaking memory is:

```
newcut.export(newtitle,format="mp3")
```

`export` returns a file handle. Now, documentation says *Write the AudioSegment object to a file – returns a file handle of the output file (you don't have to do anything with it, though).*, which AFAIK is incorrect, as explained in [this bug report](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/305). File handles have to be closed.

At present, it seems to me that all the bytes coming from the `export` are leaking. Since you're loading mp3, that's a lot - and you get memory error.

If that does not do the trick, do the following:

```
import tracemalloc
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os, eyed3

tracemalloc.start()

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\User\Music\audiobooks podcasts\Narnia\Edit Testing')

NarniaList = os.listdir()

for i in NarniaList[:2]:
    print('Ammending ' + i + '...')
    track = AudioSegment.from_mp3(i)
    newcut = track[75000:-59000]
    newtitle = 'New'+i
    newcut.export(newtitle,format="mp3")
    audiofile = eyed3.load(i)
    newfile = eyed3.load(newtitle)
    newfile.tag.artist = audiofile.tag.artist 
    newfile.tag.album = audiofile.tag.album
    newfile.tag.title = audiofile.tag.title
    newfile.tag.save()

snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')

print("[ Top 10 ]")
for stat in top_stats[:10]:
    print(stat)
```

This will get you top 10 memory consumers after processing two audio files.